# What is the use of ValueProvider class in apache beam?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, data-pipeline

I am trying to understand the purpose the ValueProvider class in Apache beam. I had seen in some examples the the Pipeline option values are wrapped by ValueProvider. But I couldn't get any relevant documentation to understand this class.

Answer (score 1):

it is specifically used to create dataflow Flexi template or we can call it custom dataflow template. for the values like PUBSUB topic/subscription link, temp location, GCS bucket, big query Dataset and tables all these configurable parameters can be passed in the template and make these template reusable and deployable. you can read further on this [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#valueprovider)